# HTML CSS Wrong zoom behaviour

Tags: html, css

I am currently sitting on a websitew-layout where the banner is fixed at the top of the  page and you can scroll the inner div. However, when I zoom in the browser (strg+'+') the banner overflows the container without  the container becomes x-scrollable. The inner-div overflows and geht scrollable.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edzrf1nb/)
css:

```
div#container
{
        /*overflow: hidden;*/
        max-width: 98vw;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto -10px;
        overflow:auto;

        }
div#main_outer {
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 90%;
    }
div.main {
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 1800px;
    min-height: 90%;
    width: 1800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    }
  div#banner {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
    font-size:25px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 1800px;
    height: 80px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffcccc;}
```

What I want is that the banner and the inner div are always having the same width with the CONTAINER becomes scrollable in x direction when they overflow
...

Comment: jsfiddle is not working? Check it @jansta

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/edzrf1nb/

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#container {
    max-width: 98vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto -10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
div.main {
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90%;
    width: 1800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
div#banner {
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
    font-size:25px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 1800px;
    height: 80px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
   <div id="banner">
   ...
   </div>
<div id="main_outer">
  <div class="main">...<div style="width:360px;height:360px; background-color:white; position:relative;bottom:2%; top:2%; left:40%;">
  </div></div>
  <div class="main">
  ..</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

This solved the issue as per i understand what you want it to be

Comment: I want the banner to stay on top. i tried the property "fixed" but this is shifting the main-div to the top...

Comment: Thank you! Yes that does exactly what I want.. at least in chromium... Using firefox it does not work as expected.. The banner goes out of the screen without the container becoming scrollable.. (instead the outer main div becomes vertically scrollable on an unrealistic scale.. it must be a bug..

Answer (score 0):

Not getting exactly what you want but as i understand may be you want like this:

```css
div#container {
    max-width: 98vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto -10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
div.main {
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90%;
    width: 1800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
div#banner {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
    font-size:25px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 1800px;
    height: 80px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="banner">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="main_outer">
      <div class="main">...
        <div style="width:360px;height:360px; background- color:white; position:relative;bottom:2%; top:2%; left:40%;"></div>       </div>
      <div class="main">
      ..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```